# How can I track the access to a disk sector in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk

I am hitting a problem in my Linux host, where a file system superblock is being written by mistake.
I tried many ways to figure out which process wrote that superblock (a disk sector), but I failed to find the root cause.
So, I am wondering if there is a way to track the write to the disk sector?

Comment: Please [can you elaborate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/464565/edit). How is a filesystem superblock being written "by mistake"?

Comment: The system is running a Database system (I am not familiar with DB), and DBA told me that DB is corrupted. The filesystem underneath is XFS, and found its superblock is not correct, and is filled with garbage data.  I need a way to capture the superblock written by which entity in Linux.

Comment: Please add that into your question so it's easy for people to read. (No "edit" or "update" message. Just add the information as if you'd provided it originally.)

Comment: Is the database trying to use a formatted partition as a raw volume?

Answer (score 1):

`auditd` tracking the right syscalls (`sync,fsync, fdatasync`) could be worth trying.
Also IO debugging in `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump` could be helpful to track that down.

Be careful with these options, to not create a loop with logfiles. Debugging disk writes to disk files will cause more disk writes that cause debugging info to be written to disk files.

Answer (score 0):

From your extremely brief description it sounds like you may have a filesystem and a raw database device sharing the same partition.

Needless to say you can't do that. Either give the partition over to the database or use the filesystem to provide a file structure in which the database can write files.